# Keyboard scroll down in Google Reader app

Tags: keyboard, google-reader

How can I use the arrow keys in my keyboard to scroll down on a page in the Google Reader app?

I can scroll down only via the tactile screen, which is not easy to be done when wearing gloves in winter time.

Comment: There are (inexpensive) gloves that work with capacitive touch screens.  http://www.agloves.com/

Comment: What about Google Reader via the Browser?  I haven't tried it recently so don't remember how well it works on Mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible.
At least not in the post it self. In the list of posts it is however.

The only way I am able to scroll in posts, is sideways, which changes the post.

It could be done programmatically though, by combining and rewriting some stuff. But then it is of course no longer Google Reader :)

A suggestion however (which is what I do) is to make a small hole in the thumb of the glove. Then the skin is able to make electric connections on the touch screen :)

Comment: No luck then. I posted the request on Google Reader's App website: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=2d12029dc59dbb51&hl=en